# Why is default view not shown?

Tags: angularjs, html, express, angular-ui-router, config

How do I make `localhost:8000` show `<p>default</p>` under HTML5 mode?

While accessing via `<a ui-sref="default">a link</a>` would always work, I always get empty content no matter I go to `localhost:8000` or `localhost:8000/`.

I have read a lot of ui-router docs and SO questions and still very confused, any help would be much appreciated.

app.module.js:

```
.config(["$locationProvider", function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
  });
}])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
  $stateProvider
    .state('default',{
      url: "/",
      template: "<p>default</p>"
    })
})
```

express.js:

```
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  //gets index.html
  res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname + '/../client' });
});
```

Comment: Why are you using `requireBase: false`?

Comment: @AnidMonsur I was following the [FAQ](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#decision-tree) since I wanted to have my default view when visiting root address.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I would try adding `<base href="/"></base>` to `<head>` and remove the `requireBase: false`.

Comment: It didn't work. But I discovered you could put default view by doing `<ui-view>default view</ui-view>`

Comment: @AnidMonsur This is so weird. After I added `.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
      function ($rootScope,   $state,   $stateParams) {
      $rootScope.$state = $state;
      $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
      }
  ])`, it works. Any ideas?